# How to: Sram 2x10 to 1x10

Tags: drivetrain

I'm thinking on converting my Sram transmission 2x10 to 1x10, this is with a single chain ring.

My biggest doubt is how to prevent cross chaining, do I need to get a special chain or how do I prevent the excessive wear out and grainy feeling when I'm in the biggest cassette ring.

Comment: I run my 'cross bike as a 1x10, all SRAM Force, bash guard in place of the big ring and a chain keeper on the inside. No problems at all.

Comment: If you can, try and use a chainring that's designed to be run in it's own, and has no shifting ramps on it. Also your crankset probably has some 2.5mm spacers both sides of the BB. Removing one from the drive side and placing it on the other side might even up your chain line a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a mountain bike, you could use a chain guide like [this one](http://www.treefortbikes.com/product/333222377971/463/MRP-S4-Chain-Guide-32-36t.html?gclid=CPugqJjKnbYCFa9aMgod7H0A6A). The rollers keep the chain aligned on the chain ring at all times and the rear provides tension as it normally would.

[image: MRPS4 Chain Guide 32-36t]

NB: I'm not necessarily recommending this one in particular, just it or something like it. I have no experience with this particular model.

I'm not sure if they make anything comparable for road setups. I wasn't able to find anything with a quick Googling.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the chainline as central as possible, it might be best to go with a tripple crank and use the center position for your chain ring and the outer for a bash guard.

A single speed crank has a [wider chainline](http://sheldonbrown.com/chainline.html#standards) and is biased towards the outside/smallest cog in the casette.

That said, I've just built a 1x9 with Stylo 1.1 cranks and SRAM X0 casette / derailler.

No dropped chains yet, with just the bash guard, and it's very smooth.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a special chain for this, and probably not much you can do about it anyway, apart from the usual drivetrain maintenance and monitoring. Having only a single ring will remove one component of cross-chain wear (rubbing on the inside of the outer ring when the chain is in the inner ring and an outer rear cog).

If you're able, use a crankset that is specifically designed for a single chainring as opposed to simply dropping rings from a double or triple. That will optimally position the chain between the extremes and reduce the chain angle, thus reducing wear.